# How to detect arguments with single or double quotes?

Tags: linux, shell

In shell (restricted Ksh):

`script1.sh "arg1 arg" arg2 'agr3 arg4' ...`

(the number of arguments and order with quoted args is random)

How to detect in script whether we used single or double quotes in arg list?

Upd: next code not find quotes if one quoted args:

`if [[ "$#" == *"\""* ]]; then
        echo "Quotes not accepted" >&2
        exit 1
fi`

Answer (score 2):

The quotes are interpreted by the shell before the command (your script `script1.sh` in this case) is invoked.  I am not sure why your script wants to know if arguments were quoted.  To achieve your goal, you need to put your arguments in two sets of quotes - use double quotes to protect single quotes and single quotes to protect double quotes, like this:

```
script1.sh '"arg1 arg"' arg2 "'arg3 arg4'" ...
```

In this case, the script would see:

```
$1 => "arg1 arg"  # double quotes are a part of the string
$2 => arg2
$3 => 'arg3 arg4' # single quotes are a part of the string
```

Then the script can check for quotes:

```
[[ "$1" = \"*\" ]] && echo "argument 1 has double quotes"
[[ "$3" = \'*\' ]] && echo "argument 3 has single quotes"
```

---

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082956/6862601

Comment: Position with quoted args are unknown ... script must have only one arg without any quoted arguments. If user specified many args (may be quoted), script must process it and throw exception.

Comment: One quoted args also not allowed - only unquoted. may be this code check it: if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then exit 1 fi;